# Debugging git hooks

Tags: git, githooks

I created a git hook that would listen for any new push on the master branch on a local repo and would take a pull on the server (where the web app is deployed) whenever it finds one.

I have referenced this [example](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks) to create my hook.

Below is the hook code:

File name & path: *.git/hooks/post-receive*

```
#!/bin/sh

set -x
echo "Pulling new commits" >> hook_receive.log
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    if [[ $ref =~ .*/master$ ]];
    then
        echo "Master ref received.  Deploying master branch to Test..."
        unset GIT_DIR
        git pull
    else
        echo "Ref $ref successfully received.  Doing nothing: only the master branch may be deployed on this server."
    fi
done
```

I have given the file execute permissions:

```
chmod +x .git/hooks/post-receive
```

I have set the `set -x` flag for debug mode and also have tried logging to the file `hook_receive.log` but nothing is being logged.
I hope I have use the correct hook.

Comment: If the push to the master branch of this repo is success, why does it need to run `git pull` in this repo?

Comment: `push` is done locally and `pull` should happen on the server

Comment: Let's make it clear first. So you have a local repo in your machine, and you deploy this post-receive hook in it. When someone else pushes new commits to the master branch of the server-side repo, you want you local repo to pull it from the server-side repo. Am I right?

Comment: No, the hook is to be deployed on the server side. Whenever I commit and push changes from my `local repo`, I want the commits to be pulled on `server-side` repo

Comment: Should I use `pre-receive` hook?

Comment: if you have pushed to the server-side repo, it's not necessary to pull again. Where does it pull from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142899/discussion-between-vaulstein-and-elpiekay).

Comment: Besides all the other comments, this example hook from the digitalocean tutorial is flawed: `$ref ~= .*/master$` means "the ref ends with `/master`", which triggers on, e.g., branch `test/master` (`refs/heads/test/master`). To check for an exact match of a specific branch, do not use regular expressions, and simply spell out the full name of the branch. In other words: `if [ "$ref" = refs/heads/master ]; then ...; fi`

Comment: I found a way to solve my problem, created a webhook that would listen for any push and would do a pull whenever a new push is done.

Comment: @ElpieKay my bad. It was exactly how you mentioned in your 2nd comment.

Comment: @Vaulstein Would you mind adding your final webhook as the answer?